# Xamarin error cs0263 partial declarations must not specify base classes

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have already looked to similar answers and I don't know why I am still have this error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0263  Partial declarations of 'MainPage' must not specify different base classes  MyNavDraw.Android   (my path ...)\MainPage.xaml.cs  13  Active
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
namespace MyNavDraw
{

    public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
    ...
```

MainPage.xaml

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNavDraw"
             x:Class="MyNavDraw.MasterDetailPage">

    <MasterDetailPage.Master>
    ...
```

What I tried so far:

In xaml I have replaced the tag to:

```
<we:MainPage ...
```

I checked "x:Class" and I think is correct the syntax, I have restarted the VS and I built again the solution.

I use Xamarin with VS 2017.

After a day (from this post question) I tried to put in comments the code of "MainPage.xaml" file. Then I saved it, I removed comments, saved it again and built the solution. I have a new error in built:

```
No way to resolve conflict between "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" and "mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e". Choosing "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" arbitrarily.
```

I have an other problem when I debug the app to my physical phone (android).

In My.Nav.Draw.Droid.MainPage.xaml.g.cs I have an exception Unhandled error.

```
 global::Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.Extensions.LoadFromXaml(this, typeof(MainPage));
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: I believe x:Class="MyNavDraw.MasterDetailPage" should be x:Class="MyNavDraw.MainPage"

Comment: I don't know. I am new developer in Xamarin and I get only this error. What can I do?

Comment: No I get the same error here.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your project name before the namespace name, also update your `xmlns:local` line too:

```
<MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProjectName.MyNavDraw;assembly:MyProjectName"
     x:Class="MyProjectName.MyNavDraw.MasterDetailPage">
```

Comment: I have too many errors. I will try to write the project again to an other solution. Please let me check it and I will answer to you what it happened.

Comment: Sure, no problem. If you still have errors just update your question

Comment: I have updated my question. I get in built a new error. 

conflict between "mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0

With my code and no changes I get the above. When I put yours I get
CS0103: The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context

CS0103: The name 'navigationDrawerList' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Is the `conflict between "mscolib...` message an error, or just a warning?

Comment: Too many errors for a simple app!!! There is a conflict and I have a new error when I am install the app to my physical phone I get an error Exception Unhandled... Find more in my updated question in 2 min.

Comment: The latest error is most likely a syntax error in your XAML markup